# удаление шумов с изображения дорожного покрытия в opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Идея в том что с с помощью treshold  находятся контуры ямы или трещины, изображение обрезается под конкретный контур и закидывается в НС. Нужно убрать лишние шумы отражающиеся в thesholde, как это сделать?

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(masked, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(blurred, 98[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1], 255, 1)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После бинаризации используйте cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats, далее оставляететолько  те компоненты, которые имеют площадь больше заданного значения. Выделять контуры не нужно.

Comment: @AlexAlex, спасибо за совет, попробую сейчас. ну вообще, после нахождения контуров я вычислял их площадь с помощью cv2.countourArea и откидывал значения меньше порогового значения

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так выделить объекты по площади, диапазон площадей надо подобрать:

```
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(threshold, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
area=output[2][:,4]
cond=(1000>area)&(area>250) # выделяем объекты с площадью от 250 до 1000 
idx=np.nonzero(cond)
mask = np.isin(output[1], idx)
cv2.imwrite('test.png', 255*np.uint8(~mask))
```

Это должно работать побыстрее контуров.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но я не до конца понимаю что возвращает cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats, и что происходит в этих строках idx=np.nonzero(cond)
mask = np.isin(output[1], idx).попробовал этот код не совсем то получается на выходе.

Comment: Что не понятно в справке по connectedComponentsWithStats?  idx=np.nonzero(cond) - находим индексы тех компонентов, которые соответствуют условию.
mask = np.isin(output[1], idx) - бинарная маска элементов idx
Условия по площади естественно  нужно подбирать под свою картинку.